# Excel COM add-in for Training The Street no longer loads after another add-in is uninstalled, reinstalling does not work

Tags: vsto, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx, logitech

My TTS Turbo Macro Excel COM add-in was working before I uninstalled Logi Options Plus for the second time.

I tried cleaning up related registry items and reinstalling TTS Turbo Macro add-in and Logi Options Plus but it didn’t help. The load behavior value of 3 for TTS add-in was correct; load count also matches the number of times I launched MS Excel, though the add-in never loaded. To further troubleshoot, I added paths related to TTS add-in to trusted location, but to no avail. I had ran into the similar situations where TTS add-in does not load; reinstalling the OS would fix it but I’d rather not waste that much time on it again. The TTS add-in also has an Excel (non-COM) add-in. When I launch Excel, I could see it’s been loaded, but nothing appears on the ribbon like before. Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot and fix the issue?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting add-in developers instead, so they will be able to troubleshoot the add-in with other add-ins. Or just fix the issue if any.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022#to-show-vsto-add-in-user-interface-errors) for more information.

Also Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2022) article.

But I'd suggest contacting add-in developers instead.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. After adding 'VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS' to my system environment variables, and setting its value to 0, I was able to get more details regarding the error. A pop-up window shows "an unhandled exception occurred in your application" at startup. Going into details, it says “String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I thought it could be related to my Windows regional format setting. I set the format to be different from the region I'm currently in due to my personal habit. After I change to the corresponding format for my region, the issue is gone!

Comment: Glad it helped to fix the issue.